# Making the state persist from it's previous state in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Consider this code:

```js
    const [newvideo, setNewVideo] = useState({
      title: '',
      url: '',
      thumbnail: ""
    })
  
    //this randomizes a json data array called 'allwaza'
    const handleRandomVideo = () => {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allwaza.length);
      const randomItem = allwaza[randomIndex];

      setNewVideo({    
        title: randomItem.title,
        url: randomItem.url,
        thumbnail: randomItem.thumbnail
      })
    }
 

  
    useEffect(() => {   
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime(new Date());
      }, 1000);

      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
      if (time.getHours() === 00 && time.getMinutes() === 00 && time.getSeconds() === 0) {
        // Call the function at midnight
        console.log("It fired: ", time.toLocaleTimeString());   
   
        handleRandomVideo()
      }
    }, [time]);
```

This updates the state so that my video changes for a new one at exactly that time. I tested it with several times and it changes fine. But, if I refresh the screen, it resolves back to the empty state, even though I modified it in the handleRandomVideo().

How can I make it persist? AsyncStorage?

Comment: LocalStorage will do. The state is pretty small (possibly < 100 bytes). And LocalStorage is synchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use some storage to persist data. because when you refresh the screen all state will initialized.

You can use some libraries for persist the data like:

- https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage
  This library is async so you should handle getData in useEffect hook
- https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv
  This library is sync so you can use it in initialization of useState
- https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist
  If you using redux, this library can persist data in redux